# angular $scope data will not changed

Tags: angularjs

My problem is that I have a $scope.page on to different controllers under the same module.

the $scope.page data should change for each route.

I'm trying to understand this...

*some code:*

```
hall.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/", { controller: 'pageForsideController', templateUrl: "pages/forside.html" })
            .when("/om", { controller: 'pageOmController', templateUrl: "pages/omMig.html" })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' })
});

hall.controller('pageOmController', function ($scope, siteData) {
    siteData.getServices(function (data) {
        $scope.services = data;
    })
    siteData.getPageByName("Mig", function (data) {       
        $scope.page = data;
    });
});

hall.controller('pageForsideController', function ($scope, siteData) {
    siteData.getPageByName("Forside", function (data) {
        $scope.page = data;
    });
});

hall.factory("siteData", function ($http) {
    return {
        getServices: function (successcb) {
            $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'data.json' })
            .success(function (data, status, headers, confic) {
                successcb(data.services);
                console.log("getServices")
            });
        },
        getPageByName: function (name, successcb) {
            $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'data.json' })
            .success(function (data, status, headers, confic) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.pages.length; i++)
                    if (data.pages[i].title == name)
                        successcb(data.pages[i]);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

### Updated:

here is a plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/9K3C3ahi5WMPeKLeL318?p=preview

Comment: I don't get it, where does the problem lie exactly? Each controller will get its own scope, they are not shared just inherited from the parent.

Comment: Really not clear what issue is....create a demo in plunker that outlines problem in better detail. Can add a file `data.json` and will work with code you have now

Comment: I think $routeProvider calls both controllers at the same time, so $scope.page gets Update. maybe? how do you avoid it?

Comment: if controller for view being set in routeprovider...don't set it in markup also...one or the other

Comment: Thank you very much, @charlietfl. it makes sense and works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP fixed the problem by following [charlieftl's instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295043/angular-scope-data-will-not-changed#comment30291729_20295043), and removing the controller from either markup or $routeProvider.